# random frame animation does not work android

Tags: android, animation, random, imageview

I am trying to achieve a random animation of from a set of images, where each frame is a random image from the image set. And for this I am using addFrame method of AnimationDrawable object but the animation is not working. I tried searching various tutorials, tried other things also but nothing helped. Below is my code of the program, can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong. In the layout there is an ImageView. But when I am trying animation from xml animation definition(which is not random), it works. Thanks and regards.

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MemoryGame extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
MemoryGameView mgv;
ImageView memImg;
int []seqimg = new int[15];
AnimationDrawable animation; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.memorylayout);
    memImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mem_img);
    memImg.setOnTouchListener(this);

    //generate the random sequence of list
    randomImgList();
    defAnimation();
  }

//select the array of random sequence of images for viewing
private void randomImgList(){
    //initialize the sequece
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        seqimg[i] = i+1;
    }
    Random rng = new Random();
    // i is the number of items remaining to be shuffled.
    for (int i = 15; i > 1; i--) {
        // Pick a random element to swap with the i-th element.
        int j = rng.nextInt(i);  // 0 <= j <= i-1 (0-based array)
        // Swap array elements.
        int tmp = seqimg[j];
        seqimg[j] = seqimg[i-1];
        seqimg[i-1] = tmp;
    }
}
//define the animation sequece
private void defAnimation() {
    animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        String imgName = "mimg" + seqimg[i];
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        Log.d("id",""+id);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(id), 1000);
    }
    animation.setOneShot(true);
}

//define the touch event from the OnTouchListener interface
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
    if(v.getId() == memImg.getId()) {
        memImg.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
        animation.setVisible(true, true);
        animation.stop();
        animation.start();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the animation is not working"? Be more specific, what exactly happens?

Comment: when i touch the imageview then it only keep showing the image with which it is initialized and the animation does not starts. i tried logging if the animation is running or not, it shows true that animation is running but i dont see any changed in the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I am posting the solution maybe if other find this problem it will be helpful.
Actually the animation is working but the initial image which is used to initialize the ImageView is above the animation so the animation was invisible. Now I set the ImageView to a blank image before starting the animation and the animation is visible now.
Thanks.